# how can i handle this "script timeout" error when executing script with python's seleniumbase Library?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api, seleniumbase

I am new to Python, and I am scraping a website with Python's seleniumbase library and need to run this fetch script intermittently. I realized that when the response time gets above approximately 950 milliseconds, it throws me a script timeout error, but I can see the fetch's response in browser's network tab. This code works fine if the delay time of the response is below 950 ms.

```
script = """
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    var csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
                    var obj;
                
                    fetch("MyUrl", {
                        'headers': {
                            'accept': '/',
                            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                            'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google       Chrome";v="116"',
                            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
                            'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                            'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                            'x-csrf-token': csrf,
                            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                        },
                        'referrer': 'MyUrl',
                        'referrerPolicy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
                        'body': 'consularid=3&exitid=1&servicetypeid=1&calendarType=2&totalperson=1',
                        'method': 'POST',
                        'mode': 'cors',
                        'credentials': 'include'
                    })
                        .then(res => res.text())
                        .then(data => {
                            obj = data;
                            resolve(obj);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            reject(error);
                        });
                });
                """
            obj_variable = sb.execute_script(script)
```

This is an error example:

```
Message: script timeout
  (Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.141)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61E0352A2+57122]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DFAEA92]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DE7E25D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DEEF314]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DED6FDA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DEEEB82]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DED6DB3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DEAD2B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DEAE494]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61E2DEF82+2849794]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61E331D24+3189156]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61E32ACAF+3160367]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61E0C6D06+653702]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DFBA208]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DFB62C4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DFB63F6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61DFA67A3]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFAFEF07614+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB007C26B1+33]
```

I tried adding a timeout to the script code, but it didn't work, maybe I didn't do it correctly.

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @D.L I have written the code, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having a script timeout issue when running the script inisde selenium.

You've said that you tried adding a timeout to the script, but that did not work out well.

One possible solution to this problem is that you can set the timeout directly in the context of the Selenium script. You can use the `setTimeout` function of javascript itself.

You can also utilize `execute_async_script` to not wait for the script execution and don't get timeout errors.

The modified version of your code:

```py
script = """
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
    var obj;

    // Set a timeout of 30 seconds (change the value as needed)
    var timeout = 30000;

    var fetchAndResolve = () => {
        fetch("MyUrl", {
            'headers': {
                'accept': '/',
                'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google       Chrome";v="116"',
                'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
                'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                'x-csrf-token': csrf,
                'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            'referrer': 'MyUrl',
            'referrerPolicy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
            'body': 'consularid=3&exitid=1&servicetypeid=1&calendarType=2&totalperson=1',
            'method': 'POST',
            'mode': 'cors',
            'credentials': 'include'
        })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(data => {
            obj = data;
            resolve(obj);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error);
        });
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
        reject(new Error("Script execution timed out"));
    }, timeout);

    fetchAndResolve();
});
"""

obj_variable = sb.execute_async_script(script)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but unfortunately that didn't work. with "execute_async_script" command it always returns script timeout with huge delay ... i also tried this edited script with "execute_script" command, it returns response if the time is below 950 ms otherwise it returns script timeout